# Ethernet connection for IP camera

Tags: router, ethernet, ip-camera

I bought a Lloyd's Advanced Home security system, the IP camera I believe is wireless, but in order to get it activated it needs Ethernet connection to my router, which I have done and still wont connect when I go online via my smartphone with the app.

I talked to my internet provider and they said I need to pay another $60 a month to use the Ethernet port, normally I just use WiFi.

I have a Broadcom 4313 router. I believe the Ethernet connection is only needed to activate the camera, then its wireless. Any suggestion on how to get this working without paying for the port I only need for a few minutes?

Comment: It sounds like the charge is for a fixed IP address, possibly needed to access your camera from outside your network, but your question is not very clear.

Comment: Assuming that the IP camera may have a static IP address assigned to its Ethernet port (check your documentation), cable the IP camera directly to a PC using an ***ad hoc*** network: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-computer-to-computer-adhoc-network#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Couple options:

- Take it to a friend's house and use their Internet to register it.
- Setup a PC to share your WiFi connection via it's Ethernet port, and then hook the camera to the Ethernet port of the PC.